# change proxy settings for Chrome and not for entire operating system

Tags: macos, google-chrome, proxy

How can I change proxy settings for Google Chrome without changing the proxy settings for entire operating system? I know that I can go to Network in System preferences, but that changes proxy settings globally.

Is is possible to do it just for Chrome? Firefox for example doesn't require changing global proxy settings.

EDIT: I am open for dirty hacks too :D

Answer (score 10):

You have to pass the proxy argument to Chrome on the command line. Run something like:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --proxy-server=http://my-proxy.com
```

Comment: Does this work for sock5 proxy?

Comment: To make it work with socks5 proxy use `--proxy-server=socks5://proxy` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can set proxies per-profile using the extension [Proxy SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif). This is a very popular extension, however you should consider the risks of trusting this (or any) extension that can modify your browser settings, page content, etc.

Comment: This solved my problem with target system traffic on VPN not being recorded with the system proxy.